# How to use if condition for specific activated value empty column filter in Google Sheets for macro (google-sheets, filter, if, else, script)?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet

I don't know how to use only the e column filter for the if condition. From b1 to e1 4 column filters are active. I want to check with an if condition if the e filter is empty. Then if should be executed, otherwise else. Else empties the filter. Here is the code that isn't working.

```
        function myFunction() {
          if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('E1').getFilter() == null) {
            var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
            .whenCellNotEmpty()
            .build();
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
            spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
            spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 0).activate();
          }
          else {
            var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
            .build();
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
            spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
            spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 0).activate();
          }
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry, it seems like I misunderstood your question. Can you please explain what you mean by "filter is empty"? You mean that it is not applied to column E? And what do you mean by "filter should be emptied"?

Comment: With an empty filter I mean a filter that does not contain a condition. I'm looking for an if condition to check that the e1 filter does not contain a condition (value).

Comment: You mean a filter criteria?

Comment: Yes, filter criteria. That's the correct word.

Comment: I understand now. I modified my answer and hope that it addresses your question correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To verify either a filter contains a `ColumnFilterCriteria` in column E

Modify the line

```
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('E1').getFilter() == null)
```

to

```
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(5) == null) {
```

Explanation:

If the filter applies tto the whole spreadsheet / data range including column E - `getFilter() == null)` will never be fulfilled, even if there is no existent filter criteria for column E.

Instead, you need to use the method `getColumnFilterCriteria(5)` which will either return you a filter criteria o `null`.